# Why does pine script 4 integer variable turn into a series[integer] when assigned in a loop?

Tags: pine-script

I have been writing a TradingView study and have this issue where I am passing a `length` variable into the `ema` function, and it gives the error:

`Cannot call 'ema' with arguments (series[float], series[integer]); available overloads: ema(series[float], integer) => series[float]`

I have narrowed down the cause of the problem to be the `length` variable being assigned in a loop.

Here is some simplified code that replicates the problem:

```
data_source = close
int length = 20

for i = 0 to 1
    length := 20
    
result := ema(data_source, length)

plot(series=result ? result : na, color=color.blue, linewidth=2, transp=0, title='Baseline')
```

The above code fails with the error above, but the following code where the `length` variable is not assigned in a loop, works fine:

```
data_source = close
int length = 20
    
result := ema(data_source, length)

plot(series=result ? result : na, color=color.blue, linewidth=2, transp=0, title='Baseline')
```

I don't understand why a simple `integer` variable turns into `series[integer]` when it is assigned in a loop.

Can anyone show me how I can assign variables inside a loop and not have them turn into `series`

Thanks for your time

UPDATE:
To save others some time, here is the result of my investigation around this issue:

- When an integer variable is assigned in a for loop it is automatically converted from a integer to a series and same goes for float.
- If you create a variable and assign it a value using the result of an expression (eg; a = b + c), if any variable in the expression is a series, the result will be a series.
- If you assign a value to an element of an array, it is automatically converted to a series.
- Once a variable becomes a series there is no way to convert it back to a simple type such as integer, float etc...
- There are many pine functions that only accept a simple type in their params and not a series, such as ema, wma, vwma, linreg, alma and others.
- A global variable can not be assigned from within a function, and so the workaround for this is to use an array, and then inside the function you can push or set the value of an item in the array. But as stated above the array values get converted to series when you do this. And the only way to return multiple values from a function is again to use a series.

I have put in a feature request to add support for converting series to simple type in the Pine Script language. You can see it here: https://trello.com/c/QA6bcL7l

Comment: Don't ask the same question in multiple forums. You risk getting different volunteers helping you concurrently, as you did here.

Comment: @PineCoders-LucF thanks for the response. Duly noted.  For the record, this is the only place I got this answer, so if I hadn't have posted here as well, I would not have known about the alternative ema option.  Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for` loops produces series. You can use [alexgrover's `Ema()` function](https://www.tradingview.com/script/kY5hhjA7-Functions-Allowing-Series-As-Length-PineCoders-FAQ/) which accepts a series period:

```
//@version=4
study("")
Ema(src,p) =>
    ema = 0.
    sf = 2/(p+1)
    ema := nz(ema[1] + sf*(src - ema[1]),src)

data_source = close
int length = 20

for i = 0 to 1
    length := 20

result = Ema(data_source, length)

plot(series=result ? result : na, color=color.blue, linewidth=2, transp=0, title='Baseline')
```

Comment: thanks for the response, much appreciated.  It is really limiting that basic things such as these can't be done: many basic built in functions can't use a series int, add to that you cant convert an series[integer] into to an integer, and that you can't convert a string to an integer.  My end goal was to create a generic study to test many indicators and I wanted to have an input that I could put a comma delimited string of params in and then in the study pass these into the selected indicator.

Comment: First you can't convert a string to an int or float.  I found a script to get around this, but it uses a for loop, and so the result gets converted ti a series[integer], then you can't pass a series[integer] into many built in indicator functions, and finally you can't convert a series[integer] into an integer.  It seems very restrictive.  Anyway thanks for your help here, I will push on and see how far I can get.

Comment: Pine definitely has its own way of doing things, and learning what can and cannot be done is certainly a challenge at first. After a while though, you'll see; while it may not always be intuitive, there is very often a way to accomplish what we want to do.

Comment: Thanks for the words of encouragement.  Just on the off chance that you may know a way, is it possible to convert a series[integer] to an integer?  And also is there anywhere we can go to make feature requests for pine, and see a roadmap of what features they are planning to add?

Comment: No, series cannot be converted to non-series variables. To plan your project and avoid dead ends, it's critical to understand Pine's unique [type system](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Type_system.html) and consult the refman to know the argument types expected for the function parameters you will be using.  
You can make suggestions [here](https://trello.com/c/QA6bcL7l).  
We don't publish an official roadmap, but the coming blog post which will be a wrap up of 2020 for Pine will mention a few priorities for the coming year.

Comment: ok great, thanks for taking the time to answer my questions, much appreciated.

Comment: I just ran into the same dead end. Very frustrating that this basic functionality doesn't exist.

Comment: The Pine forms reflect when a variable is known. "const" form variables are known at compile time, "input" and "simple" forms are known at bar zero, and values that are only known on each bar are of "series" form. That's the reason why `for` loops produce "series" values. The reason why no native `ta.ema()` function accepts a "series" length is that the EMA calc is recursive, so changes in length on any bar would theoretically require recalculation over the whole dataset, which cannot be done. Close approximations of EMA can, however, be achieved that support varying lengths.

Comment: @PineCoders-LucF This issue is valid for the `ta.ema()` because it would break the function itself. But a `plotchar`'s `char` argument also cannot accept a _series_ type but a constant, while every element of a series could be used as a constant (we are practically talking about pointers). So one cannot write `plotchar(condition, char = condition2 ? "X" : "Y" )`, the `char` argument has to be constant. In this case every element of the series would be independent of the others so it would not produce such issues as with the `ta.ema()`

Comment: Yes, 100% on the fact that contrary to EMA, there is no conceptually invalid reason for not allowing `plotchar()` to display series strings. The limitations here are practical; barring deep-seated architectural changes in the Pine runtime and the TV charting engine, series strings are not possible for `plotchar()`. The workaround is to use labels, which come with the 500 limit on qty. PineCoders have repeatedly asked the Pine team about allowing series strings in `plotchar()` in the last 2Y. They are usually amazingly open to changes, but the answer on this change is always a firm "can't do".

Comment: A workaround for the case you mention would be to use two `plotchar()` calls, each plotting one of the two characters, by adding `and condition2` and `and not condition2` to your `condition` boolean.